# How to fix problem: TypeError: self.env.emit is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, antd, umijs

When executing the command "yarn create umi", then select antd in the step "What functionality do you want to enable? antd" and then press ENTER, the whole process will always exit and get the following exception:
? What functionality do you want to enable? antd
events.js:298
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

TypeError: self.env.emit is not a function
at /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:653:22
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Generator instance at:
at Immediate. (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:668:20)
at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /usr/local/bin/create-umi
Arguments:
Directory: /data/projects/umi1
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.

How to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have confirmed that the following solution works:
Modify global package.json which is usually at /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/package.json,

then add the "resolutions" block as the following. After that, the package.json should look like:

```
<code>    
{
  "dependencies": {
    "create-umi": "^0.20.1"
  },
 "resolutions": {
    "create-umi/yeoman-generator": "4.5.0"
  }
}
</code>
```

after the change, run again with yarn create umi